In Teams action based message extension how to enable SSO, and get valid graph api access token
My bot is based on Teams ai library, I want to access graph API in an action based message extension. I want to redirect user to consent dialog when user has not consent app, other wise open the task adaptive card.
Following is my code:
IConfidentialClientApplication msal = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.AppId)
                                       .WithClientSecret(config.AppPassword)
                                       .WithTenantId(config.AppTenantId)
                                       .WithLegacyCacheCompatibility(false)
                                       .Build();

AuthenticationOptions<AppState> options = new();
options.AddAuthentication("graph", new TeamsSsoSettings(new string[] { "User.Read" }, signInLink, msal));

var appBuilder = new ApplicationBuilder<AppState>()
        .WithAIOptions(new(actionPlanner))
        .WithStorage(storage)
        .WithLoggerFactory(loggerFactory)
        .WithTurnStateFactory(() => new AppState())
        .WithAuthentication(adapter, options);

Application<AppState> app = appBuilder.Build();
app.MessageExtensions.OnFetchTask("myaction", fetchTaskHandler);

fetchTaskHandler is a function to handle composeExtension/fetchTask activity, I want to access graph API in this method, but I cannot get user access token for graph API when user didn't consent app.
My question is how can I prompt user to consent app when click action command? I tried to send an OAuth card or sign in suggested actions in fetchTaskHandler, but all of them are not supported.

Could you please try like this?
 return new MessagingExtensionActionResponse
{
    Task = new TaskModuleContinueResponse
    {
        Value = new TaskModuleTaskInfo
        {
            Card = new SigninCard("Please sign in", "Sign in", "https://your-login-url").ToAttachment(),
            Height = 200,
            Width = 400,
            Title = "Login Required"
        }
    }
};


extension display unable to reach app, please try again even response is OK. As sign in card descripted, message extension does not support sign in card .

@YonF - Instead of using a sign-in card, you can provide a text message with a link that redirects the user to the consent page.
In the link you can add the parameters for initiating the OAuth flow and obtaining consent.
When you click on the link, it will be redirected to the consent page.
After the granting the consent, it will be redirected back to your application's redirect URI, where you can handle further processing.

@Nivedipa-MSFT Including an open link element in adaptive card body can help me redirect to consent page, but link will be opened in browser but not teams client, opened task dialog in teams client cannot know whether consent finished. I want to access graph api in fetch task, is there any other method to do this?

@YonF - To handle user consent within the Teams client for Graph API access, you can consider using the Resource-specific consent (RSC) feature. RSC allows your Teams app to request permissions to access specific resources, such as teams or chats, within an organization directly from the Teams client. This way, you can manage the consent process without redirecting users to a browser.
Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/app-permissions/teams-app-permissions
